# RMI pass by reference call without implementing Serializable

Tags: rmi

I call a method of a remote object from a client with signature `add(Remote object)`.
That is I pass a Remote Object as a parameter to `add(Remote Object)` remote method of a remote object.

The object that I pass as parameter implements the Remote and Serializable interfaces and it is copied by value.

If I implement the Remote interface only it cannot be deserialized in the add(Remote object) method.

I want to pass it by reference.

If I extend the UnicastRemoteObject problems are solved as suggested in StackOverflow but I have a restriction by the API not to extend UnicastRemoteObject. (The framework I use calls the constructor of this class extending the UnicastRemoteObject without try catch and that throws RemoteExceptions without handling them)

**Is there another solution besides extending the UnicastRemoteObject class for passing by reference?**
Is there another class like UnicastRemoteObject whose constructor does not throw RemoteExceptions to extend?

I sifted up all Stackoverflow questions and except for extending the UnicastRemoteObject I see that I have to implement Remote interface which does not work since it cannot be serialized/deserialized.

Comment: If you can't extend `UnicastRemoteObject` you must export it yourself with `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject()`. You don't need to make it `Serializable`.

Comment: In fact implementing `Serializable` would not constitute pass-by-reference.